# How to search a given word in word file by C#

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

How can I check that a word file is contain a given word or not?

Example:
     I want to write a function: bool IsContain(string word, string filePath).
     The function will return true if **filePath** is contain **word**. Otherwise it will return false.

This is my solution with Aspose framework. Is there any better solution?

```
public class FindContentOfWordDoc
{
    public bool FindContent(string filePath, string content)
    {
        var doc = new Document(filePath);

        var findReplaceOptions = new FindReplaceOptions
        {
            ReplacingCallback = new FindCallBack(),
            Direction = FindReplaceDirection.Backward
        };

        var regex = new Regex(content, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        doc.Range.Replace(regex, "", findReplaceOptions);

        return (findReplaceOptions.ReplacingCallback as FindCallBack)?.IsMatch ?? false;
    }

    private class FindCallBack : IReplacingCallback
    {
        public bool IsMatch { get; private set; }
        ReplaceAction IReplacingCallback.Replacing(ReplacingArgs e)
        {
            IsMatch = true;
            return ReplaceAction.Stop;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried with Aspose frameword. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Are you talking about _Microsoft Word_?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about MS Word.

Comment: Have you tried reading the entire file as string and check from there? AFAIR normally the texts are not encrypted in word documents.

Comment: No, I did not try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Aspose library as stated in your comment you can achieve this through a customised implementation of the IReplacingCallback interface.

```
bool IsContain(string word, string filePath)
{
    Document doc = new Document(filePath);

    OccurrencesCounter counter = new OccurrencesCounter();

    doc.Range.Replace(new Regex(word), counter, false);

    return counter.Occurrences > 0;

}


private class OccurrencesCounter : IReplacingCallback
{
    public ReplaceAction Replacing(ReplacingArgs args)
    {
        mOccurrences++;

        return ReplaceAction.Skip;
    }


    public int Occurrences
    {
        get { return mOccurrences; }
    }

    private int mOccurrences;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the snippet using VSTO:

```
if (Application.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref 
missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref 
missing, 
ref missing, ref missing)) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("Text found.");
} 
else
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("The text could not be located.");
}
```

Comment: It does not work with MS Word

Comment: It's true. Sorry about this. I didn't understood the question correctly.

I think that snippet works!